# start activity with fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, fragment

I want to start `activity` with three `fragments`

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(NewMealActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("id", 1);
            startActivity(intent);
```

`MainActivity` includs three `fragments` (Frag1, Frag2, Frag3).
I want to open Frag3, but opens Frag1

This is my MainActivity with three tabs

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private String txtFragmentMyData;
private String txtFragmentProductList;
private String txtFragmentCalorieCalculator;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private  long tabId;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txtFragmentMyData = getString(R.string.txt_fragment_my_data);
    txtFragmentProductList = getString(R.string.txt_fragment_product_list);
    txtFragmentCalorieCalculator = getString(R.string.txt_fragment_calorie_calculator);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);

    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(txtFragmentMyData));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(txtFragmentProductList));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(txtFragmentCalorieCalculator));

    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    final ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        tabId = extras.getLong("id");
    }
    if (tabId > 0){
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
    } else {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
    }
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
}
```

}

I want, that at the first start opens first tab, but if I click on buttom in another activity opens third tab

Comment: if you are using `viewpager` then use `setCurrentItem(position)` so no matter whats your implementation is, there will be similar function to display fragment

Comment: paste  code it helpful for developer

Comment: how you are showing fragments in your main activity? In a view pager ?

Comment: @vinod yes, in a view pager

Comment: @AndriiAfanasenko  then check how you are implementing your pager adapter and  use setcurrentItem() method on viewpager instance in onCreate method of hosting activity.

Comment: @vinod 
I updated the question

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar I updated the question

Comment: Instead of getLong on extras, can you try directly using getIntExtra on intent you receive

Comment: @vinod, not works